# Encrypting Attributes in SAML Assertion

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

In B2C Policy, we can use the attribute "assertionsencrypted" to encrypt the Assertions sent back to the SP.

How can we encrypt only the Attributes of the Assertions(SAML Core 2.0 Spec: Section 6 specifies that the Attributes also can be encrypted in the Assertion)?